How do I determine the bare minimum Debian package requirements to run BIND9?
I want to create a Debian based DNS Server to run BIND9.
There is plenty of information on package dependencies. but it is all about how to install required packages when installing package-x.y.z. However, I cannot find anything about how to find out all the packages that are not required by package-x.y.z and uninstall them.
What I want to be able to do is get the answer to this question:
What are the absolute minimum set of packages required in order to successfully run BIND9, such that I can uninstall (or not install in the first place) all packages that are not required (directly or indirectly) in order to run BIND9?
For example, it's obvious that named/bind requires network connectivity, else it could not serve inbound DNS queries, so we know all packages and drivers for IP networking will be required. We also know we must have NTP because that serves a pretty important time keeping function which, although maybe not directly required or used by the named/bind process, is definitely indirectly required in order to enforce DNSSEC and other PKI tasks. We obviously also need everything for local user authentication, and also for running the SSH service to allow server management.
Perhaps I really should be asking - what is the absolute bare minimum Debian install that I can build, onto which I would only need to install BIND9?

Does this "absolute bare minimum" thing need to boot? Does it need to manage a bootloader? Does it need to install and upgrade kernels? Or will all of that be provided by something else? "Absolute bare minimum" might seem to be something obvious to you, but it doesn't have to mean the same thing for everyone

How will you update the zones that the DNS server will be authoritative for?  Over the network (likely requiring TSL/SSL certificates and a way to manage them on the server)?  Configuration management to fetch zone files from somewhere and write them into BIND9's directories?  Ssh into the server and edit zone files by hand?  Managing a DNS server can involve more dependencies than just installing/running/patching the bind daemon.  Where will you send your bind daemon's activity/error logs for monitoring/observability?  Datadog/NewRelic/Elasticsearch, requiring a client daemon?

That is true @muru. I do think the definition of "bare minimum" is definitely open to debate. But since I said it must be able to run BIND9 (and all that it requires), we can take that to be the bare minimum: so the question becomes "what are the bare minimum requirements to successfully run BIND9"? I think it is fare to say that whenever we talk of 'bare minimum requirements', the system in question will always have at least one main purpose for existing, and that purpose is ultimately what dictates what those bare minimum requirements are. To run BIND9 implies to boot.

Agreed, @SottoVoce, there are other functions that would be required for essential server maintenance and BIND admin. It would also be fare to say that when we design network and/or server infrastructure, we start with the high level questions, like "do I want to resolve my own DNS queries or not?" and then we choose the right application for the task, then the right OS for the application, and finally the right hardware for the OS. We don't choose hardware then design server applications based on the hardware. That would make little business sense.

@skeetastax not necessarily, if your system is just a container running in some container orchestration system. In that case, you don't need a kernel, a boot loader, a service management system, or even to boot

@muru I probably should have clarified that I was not talking about a container, but rather a fully autonomous system (either virtual or physical, which would determine what specific low-level hardware drivers are required).

For a stand-alone hardware server or VM:
Step 1.) install Debian "base system" and nothing else. This should automatically provide you with a minimalist system that can still boot on its own and update itself over an internet connection, both of which I consider basic requirements for any sort of modern stand-alone installation.
After this step you can run apt list --installed to review the current state. Anything marked as [installed,automatic] is there because something else depends on it. Pay attention to the package wich are marked just [installed].
If you remove a non-automatic package that causes a dependency, the package management will suggest the automatic package(s) that are no longer depended on by anything for uninstallation.
Step 2.) apt install bind9 and review any dependencies that are of the type Recommends:. I actually prefer the aptitude package management UI for this kind of minimalist installation work - it can display dependencies both in normal and reverse direction (i.e. "this package is depended on/recommended by/suggested by these other packages") before actually installing anything.
Step 3.) See if you need anything else, e.g. the openssh-server package if you want SSH access, or tools for DNS zone file or log management.
Step 4.) You're done!
For building a containerized service, there is usually a container build tool (docker-compose or similar) to which you specify what you need (i.e. bind9), and which can then automatically fill in any dependencies. The resulting container should have everything needed to satisfy your stated requirements and nothing more.

apt list --installed | grep -v 'installed,automatic'
